# Make a 2cell diagram more beautiful (or less ugly)

Tags: lyx, diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

I want to draw a two-cell diagram using xypic, the problem is that the bigone label is to long, how can I make the following diagram:

[image]

looks like this one:

[image]

using exclusively the two-cell feature of xypic, or at least, keep the `\uppertwocell` and `\lowertwocell` commands and draw a `{=>}` arrow using `-|` feature.

Here is the code:

```
\xymatrix{\star &  & \star\lltwocell_{g{}_{1}g{}_{2}}^{g''_{1}g''_{2}}<7>{^{(\alpha'\circ\beta')\bullet(\alpha\circ\beta)}}}
```

Knowing that the second diagram was drawn using `\ar` commands, but in LyX environment, which prevent from scrolling horizontally the window, using only `\ar` commands is not very comfortable!

Comment: Just so you know: horizontal scrolling is coming. Not in LyX 2.1, but probably 2.2.

Comment: Very good news! I hope it will not be after I finished my thesis :-D

Answer (score 2):

One approach with [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\star 
  \arrow[from=rr,bend right,"g_1 g_2"{above,name=U}] 
  \arrow[from=rr,bend left,"g_1'' g_2''"{below,name=D}] & 
(\alpha' \circ \beta') \bullet (\alpha \circ \beta) 
  \arrow[equal,from=U,shorten <=0.3333em] % 0.3333em from default inner sep value
  \arrow[Rightarrow,to=D,shorten >=0.3333em] & 
\star
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]